# Express get request empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express, http-headers

I would send data from angular to Express.

in my service ;

```
sendtext(text): Observable<any> {
  console.log(text);
  return this.http.post<string>(this.url, text, httpOptions);
}
```

I configure headers

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  })
```

my console.log(text) prints me the right text typed in an input.

In my server side I have created my server.js file

```
var http = require("http");
var admin = require('firebase-admin');
var firebase = require("firebase");
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var routerProj = require("./routes/routes");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var port = process.env.app_port || 8080; // set our port
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
var server = app.listen(port);

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT ,DELETE');

  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept,*");
  next();
});
var config = {
   ......configuration...
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);


var serviceAccount = require("./ServiceAcountKey.json");
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://datatable-18f93.firebaseio.com"
});
app.use("/v1", routerProj);
//Create HTTP server and listen on port 8000 for requests

// Print URL for accessing server
console.log("Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/");
```

And I have created my router file:

```
var express = require("express"); // call express
var router = express.Router(); // get an instance of the express Router
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
router
  .route("/")
  .post(function (req, res, err) {
    console.log(req.body);
    // Get a database reference to our posts
    var db = admin.database();
    var ref = db.ref("/");

    // Attach an asynchronous callback to read the data at our posts reference
    ref.push(
      {
        "text": req.body
      }

    );

  });
module.exports = router;
```

Here console.log(req.body) prints an empty object `{}`

Is it because of the headers ? if yes how can I configure them ? I have already tried`'Content-Type': 'application/json'`, and without headers, no result.

Comment: What is the value of `console.log(text);`?

Comment: Prints text typed in my html input component

Comment: Can you post it here with your question?

Comment: Try  `return this.http.post<string>(this.url, { text }, httpOptions)` with `Content-Type` headers set to `application/json`

Comment: That worked when I have used `{}` why does is not work without ?